# how to extract a trigrams from a string in Java with Stream

Tags: java, string, data-structures, java-stream, collectors

Let's say I have a String = "abcabc". trigrams are all unique consecutive groups of three letters, in this case

```
abc
bca
cab
```

I would like to extract them and put them inside a Map, ideally counting them.
So I'll get

```
abc, 2
bca, 1
cab, 1
```

I would like to do that with Streams, not with loops.

My idea is

1. convert the string to a HashMap: (index, 3-characters String)
2. collect, group, and count over the stream of the Map values

But I can't put it in code...

I came up with something like this:

```
        String testString = "abcabc";
        //I can't get point 1...this doesn't compile
        Map trigrams = IntStream.range(0, testString.length()-2).collect(Collectors.toMap(i->i, testString.substring(i,i+3));

        //point 2 seems to work
        //Map<Integer,String> trigrams =  Map.of(0,"abc", 1, "bca",2,"cab",3,"abc");
        
        List<String> trigramsList = trigrams.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
        Map<String, Long> result = trigramsList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Also I'm not convinced about IntStream, maybe there is another way.

Comment: `IntStream.rangeClosed(0, testString.length() - 3).mapToObj(i -> testString.substring(i, i + 3))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be simplified somewhat.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "a";

        Map<String, Long> map = IntStream.range(0, s.length() - 2)
                .mapToObj(i -> s.substring(i, i + 3))
                .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()));

        System.out.println(map);
    }
}
```

But, keep in mind that `substring()` method will throw an exception if the second index is greater than the length of the string or the second index is less than the first. This only works because `IntStream.range()` generates numbers in ascending order. So, `IntStream.range(0, -2)` returns an empty stream.

It would be better if you explicitly check that there are at least 3 characters in the string.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be to use Guava [Mutliset](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html):

```java
Mutliset trigrams = IntStream.range(0, testString.length()-2)
    .mapToObj(i->testString.substring(i,i+3))
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(Mutltiset::new));
```

If you don't want to use Google library, it could be done like so:

```
Map trigrams = IntStream.range(0, testString.length()-2)
    .mapToObj(i->testString.substring(i,i+3))
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x->x, Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very well possible with streams:

```
    String testString = "abcabc";
    Map<String, Long> trigramCnt = 
            // range through index 0-3
            IntStream.rangeClosed(0, testString.length() - 3)
            // create substrings abc (idx 0-2), bca (idx 1-3), cab (idx 2-4), abc (idx 3-5)    
            .mapToObj(i -> testString.substring(i, i + 3))
            // count them
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
    System.out.println(trigramCnt);
    //-> {bca=1, abc=2, cab=1}
```